# How does Script has different outcome when executed in command line compared to when executed in build step

Tags: oracle, powershell, jenkins-plugins

I have a powershell script that is being used to connect to an Oracle database, from which I would query for certain fields. The scripts begins like this:

```
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data.OracleClient")
```

Which when executed via commandline

```
        PS C:\Users\MyuserID\Documents\DBtest> .\DBtest.ps1
```

yields the following output:

```
        GAC    Version        Location                                                                                         
        ---    -------        --------                                                                                         
        True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e0...
```

This is followed by certain select statement which work as expected and return with the rows we have queried

However when I attempt to execute the same in a Jenkins Build step either through inserting the command inside the build step or 
invoking it via the absolute path, I get this as the outcome :

```
        Started by user MyuserID
        Building in workspace E:\Datapower\Jenkins\workspace\powershell_remote_execute
        [powershell_remote_execute] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'D:\TEMP\jenkins5910047931722903259.ps1'"

        GAC    Version        Location                                                 
        ---    -------        --------                                                 
        True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.O...
        Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Attempt to load Oracle client 
        libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running 
        in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed."
        At C:\Users\MyuserID\Documents\DBtest\DBtest.ps1:13 char:3
        +         $connection.Open()
        +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
            + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException



        Finished: SUCCESS
```

It doesn't take much to figure out that Jenkins is choosing the 32bit Binaries to connect when it is meant to choose 64 bit:

```
        GAC    Version        Location                                                 
        ---    -------        --------                                                 
        True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.O...
```

Edit: I'm not explicitly invoking the x86 executable, I'm just passing the.
[command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYp98.png)
or
[filepath to the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MPOy.png)

Can someone guide me in understanding how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use the `Add-type` cmdlet with `-path` parameter to load the assembly with the literal path to the 64 bit Version?

Comment: What happens if you specify powershell.exe with the full path to the 64-bit version? `C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Comment: @T-me : let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the x86 executable?

Rather than:

```
[powershell_remote_execute] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'D:\TEMP\jenkins5910047931722903259.ps1'"
```

Try

```
[powershell_remote_execute] $ "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass" "& 'D:\TEMP\jenkins5910047931722903259.ps1'"
```

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect your comments...... I also attemtped :     `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File C:\Users\User\Documents\DBtest\DBtest.ps1` as you advised, but it still yields the same outcome